# How to make the div width fit the table which inside the div?

Tags: html, css

If the `table` is inside the `div` and the width of the table is uncertain, which can be even wider than the screen width, how to make the `div` containing that table adjust the table width? Since the `div` has been set `padding: 10px`, when the table exceeds the screen width, the `padding-right` turns invisible.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-hover table-bordered"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the context of this code and also provide the CSS? a jsFiddle would be awesome (http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Well, think this code isn't enough to solve your problem, Please place your HTML and CSS code to solve your problem, or create DEMO on [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  found a method.

```
.panel-body{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

the key why it can work is "display".You could learn the differences from block,inline,and inline-block. 
hope it helps

Comment: This solved my problem. But the panel-body and the table are not displaying full-width based on the screen resolution. If the screeen resolution is 1440px * 900px, only when the table min-width set to, e.g., 1130px, the panel-body looks normal, but still looks abnormal if the screen resolution changed.

Comment: I don't understand what you say,can you code a demo in JSbin or Jsfiddle?

Comment: +1 This worked for me, but it's not clear why. My div is inside a popup (created using divs), and I could put anything into the div, its size fitted the width of the widest one, *except when the widest contained element was a table*. The table always overflowed horizontally, and the width of the div fitted the second widest element. I cannot explain this phenomenon based on the definition of `inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofhmL6q0/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td> R1C1 </td>
        <td> R1C2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> R2C1 </td>
        <td> R2C2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> R3C1 </td>
        <td> R3C2 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0%;
}

.panel-body
{
    margin:0%;
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    height:auto;
    padding:5px 0px;
}

.panel-body table
{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```